# Race Condition of Backbone.Collection fetch

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm generating date list in a selected month where for every date, I will make a `Backbone.Collection` fetch.

Here is how I loop for every single date in a month

```
for (var i = 1; i <= numOfDays; i++) {
   var d = i < 10 ? '0'+i:i;
   var v = new View({
      dt: this.year + this.month + (d),
      param: this.array
   });      
   this.$el.append(v.render().el);
}
```

As you can see above, each view (`backbone.view`) will represent a `date` and `param object`. Then I loop the `param` object using **UnderscoreJs** `_.each` method upon callin render()

```
_.each(this.param, this.reading, this);
```

and later it will initiate a new object of `backbone.collection` and perform **fetch** right away.

```
reading: function (value, key) {
   var _this = this;
   this.fetchData(new Data.Collection(), '/api/ + value.ipid').done(function(coll) {
      var input = $('<input>').val(value.ipid).attr('data-inid', coll.first().get('in_id'));
      _this.$el.append(input);
   });
}
```

I separate a function `this.fetchData` like this

```
fetchData: function (obj, url) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred(),
        collection = obj;           
    collection.url = url;
    var xhr = collection.fetch().done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        deferred.resolve(collection, data, textStatus, jqXHR);
    }).fail(deferred.reject);
    var promise = deferred.promise();
    promise.abort = _.bind(xhr.abort, xhr);
    return promise;     
}
```

Unfortunately, for each *view*, the **order** of item inside `param` object will shift because it depends on race condition of `backbone.ajax`. Let see the items of `param` object

```
[{ipid: 44, measure: "cumec"},{ipid: 45, measure: "meter"},{ipid: 46, measure: "milimeter"}{ipid: 47, measure: "cumec"}]
```

The object items are in proper order. 44, 45, 46 and 47. But to get the listing as we pass it initially will change after **fetch** operation.

How do I tell backbonejs or underscorejs to wait every fetch operation to complete before start looping another item inside `param` object

I just want the loop (**_.each**) to wait for the fetch operation to complete before it continue looping

Hope somebody can enlighten the way to achieve this. Thank you and have a good day

Comment: It'd be useful if you post the view code which creates the collection and fetch its content too, to get a handle on the whole picture.

Comment: hi thanks for response. See my updated question above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create and append the DOM element at view creation time (i.e. inside the `reading` function), then reference from inside the done callback, the elements will be in the same order as inside your param array.

Side note: You can instantiate the `collection` with the url directly, and there is no need to wrap another jQuery promise around the promise returned by fetch.

Comment: hi thanks for response. I don't get your answer. However I update my question. Which you can see I append the `$el`

Comment: You need to move the `var input = $('<input>')` and the `this.$el.append(input)` out of the done callback.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution to your problem is using [the iterator provided by Async.js library](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachSeries), so your code would look like:

```
async.eachSeries(this.param, _.bind(this.reading, this), yourCallbackWhenTheArrayIsFinished);

reading: function (value, callback) {
   var _this = this;
   this.fetchData(new Data.Collection(), '/api/ + value.ipid').done(function(coll) {
      var input = $('<input>').val(value.ipid).attr('data-inid', coll.first().get('in_id'));
      _this.$el.append(input);
      callback();
   });
}
```

So until callback() is called from the done handler, eachSeries doesn't process the next element